# use of moved value, which is non-copyable [E0382] [E0277]

Tags: vector, iterator, rust, clone, ownership

I have an ownership problem which I don't understand well. Basically I try to create some hardlinks on my file system and to remove them after being created. Therefore I created a range of integers which I map to the actual file names I like to create and destroy. My naive solution looks like this:

```
use std::fs;

const src_file: &'static str = "a.txt";
const file_ext: &'static str = ".txt";

fn create_hardlink(dest_file: &str) {
    fs::hard_link(&src_file, &dest_file);
}

fn main() {

    let create = (0..10000).map(|x| x.to_string() + file_ext);
    let remove = (0..10000).map(|x| x.to_string() + file_ext);

    for file in create {
        create_hardlink(&file);
    }

    for file in remove {
        fs::remove_file(&file);
    }
}
```

But what I actually like to accomplish is a solution, where I don't have to repeat my self for creating the static collection with the file-names and can reuse `files` for a second for-loop:

```
...

fn main() {

    let files = (0..10000).map(|x| x.to_string() + file_ext);

    for file in files {
        create_hardlink(&file);
    }

    for file in files {
        fs::remove_file(&file);
    }
}
```

So when I try this the compiler complains, that the second usage of `files` is not possible,

```
src/main.rs:20:17: 20:22 error: use of moved value: `files` [E0382]
src/main.rs:20     for file in files {
```

because `files` already moved into the first for-loop:

```
src/main.rs:16:17: 16:22 note: `files` moved here because it has type `core::iter::Map<core::ops::Range<i32>, [closure@src/main.rs:14:36: 14:64]>`, which is non-copyable
```

after reading the explanation for `rustc --explain E0382` I decided to change the code as follows:

```
...

fn main() {

    let files = Rc::new(RefCell::new((0..10000).map(|x| x.to_string() + file_ext)));

    for file in files.clone() {
        create_hardlink(&file);
    }

    for file in files.clone() {
        fs::remove_file(&file);
    }
}
```

But this does not work as expected to me:

```
src/main.rs:16:5: 18:6 error: the trait `core::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for the type `alloc::rc::Rc<core::cell::RefCell<core::iter::Map<core::ops::Range<_>, [closure@src/main.rs:14:53: 14:81]>>>` [E0277]
src/main.rs:16     for file in files.clone() {
src/main.rs:17         create_hardlink(&file);
src/main.rs:18     }
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:16:5: 18:6 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:16:5: 18:6 help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:16:5: 18:6 note: `alloc::rc::Rc<core::cell::RefCell<core::iter::Map<core::ops::Range<_>, [closure@src/main.rs:14:53: 14:81]>>>` is not an iterator; maybe try calling `.iter()` or a similar method
src/main.rs:16     for file in files.clone() {
src/main.rs:17         create_hardlink(&file);
src/main.rs:18     }
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:16:5: 18:6 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:16:5: 18:6 note: required by `core::iter::IntoIterator::into_iter`
src/main.rs:16     for file in files.clone() {
src/main.rs:17         create_hardlink(&file);
src/main.rs:18     }
```

What can I do? Do I really have to implement the `core::iter::Iterator` for the type `alloc::rc::Rc<core::cell::RefCell<core::iter::Map<core::ops::Range<_>` like `rustc --explain E0277` is telling me? I hope not...

Is there a simple solution like defining `files` statically as `static`or as `const`? Or is my approach with mapping a `Range` non rusty?

Why do I have a type like `<core::iter::Map<core::ops::Range<_>` and not something like `<core::iter::String>`?

I hope you can help me out with that and enlighten a bit the Rust ownership principle to a novice like me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust iterators are only forward iterators, as far as I understand, so they can only be iterated once. You can either `collect` them into a vector or use a function to generate your iterator:

```rust
// 1st option
let files: Vec<_> = (0..10000).map(|x| x.to_string() + file_ext).collect();

for f in &files { ... } // Borrow `files`

// 2nd option
let files = || (0..10000).map(|x| x.to_string() + file_ext);

for f in files() { ... } // Call the closure to get an iterator
```

Comment: I'd say that the first option is *the* idiomatic solution. The second option will result to extra 10000 allocations because the range will be run through twice.

Comment: But the first one will allocate all memory at once, depending on the amount of files that might not be so nice either.

Comment: Thank you for your solutions and comments! Would it be a valuable approach to create a macro to avoid the double allocation from option 2 like this? `macro_rules! files_vec {
    ( $range:expr ) => {
        $range.map(|x| x.to_string() + file_ext).collect()
    }
}` which is quite inflexible, but pre compiled

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here.

The first is that calling

```
for f in files { ... }
```

will take `files` by value. This is avoidable by taking a reference instead:

```
for f in &files { ... }
```

because `(&foo).into_iter()` effectively resolves to `foo.iter()`.

---

The second is that `files` must be `mut`, and the reference `&mut` if you are iterating an iterator. If you had some vector, it would make sense to iterate `&my_vector` - you can iterate it without modifying it. However, if you have an iterator itself, the state is kept and updated in the iterator itself.

```
let mut files = (0..10000).map(|x| x.to_string() + file_ext);

for file in &mut files {
    create_hardlink(&file);
}

for file in files {
    fs::remove_file(&file);
}
```

---

The third is that even if you did these things, since you are using a single iterator, you can only iterate each element once! The second loop will be empty. This is the problem @filmor offers solutions for.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! As you point out my code makes more sense not to have an iterator and thus I accepted the answer from @filmor.